# Compiler thinks I am passing std::ofstream*&, passing std::ofstream*

Tags: c++, pointers

I've recently written a logger class. When compiling this code:

```
std::ofstream *stream = new std::ofstream;
stream->open( log_file_name.c_str() );

assert( stream->is_open() );

logger( stream, std::string("blurp") );
```

I get the error:

```
no match for call to '(name::space::logger)( std::ofstream*&, std::string )'
```

with regards to the last line of code.

The header file that defines logger is:

```
namespace name {
    namespace space {
        class logger {
private:                
            std::ofstream *stream;
            std::string name;
public:                
            void log( std::string, std::string );
            logger( std::ofstream *, std::string );
            logger();
        };
    }
}
```

And I have implemented all functions/constructors prototyped there without mistake.

What could be causing this? Thanks for your time, Erkling.

Comment: I compiled your code and it worked. BTW, don't use a pointer to ofstream, bad coding style.

Comment: Post a test-case. It could be as simple as not having included the required header files.

Comment: This may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172759/g-gives-me-strange-function-call-in-an-expected-error-message

Comment: Is this a linker or compiler error?

Comment: `const std::string&`! `std::ofstream&`! Don't use unnecessary pointers. Don't copy string unnecessary!

Comment: @billz
Why is it bad practice? I thought it a logical thing to do in my use case. Quoted from another comment of mine below: " I want several logger classes that write to the same file. I wasn't sure on multiple fstreams to a single file, and since my program is single-threaded, I didn't think using a single stream would cause data racing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler thinks you're calling `operator()` on an object called `logger`. It seems what you want to do is to create a `logger` instance:

```
logger log(stream, std::string("blurp") );
```

Here, `log` is an instance of class `name::space::logger`.

Comment: There is no object called logger as far as I can see. `logger(stream, string("blurp"));` would call the constructor, creating an unnamed temporary. Unless I am failing to see some "most vexing parse"-like problem.

Comment: This was my problem. The code was in a constructor for another class, and logger was a member of the class. I mistakenly thought that the syntax applied for a default-constructor'd object.
    
    logger = name::space::logger( stream, std::string("blurp") );

fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to use a pointer for the `ostream`. Since this is not Java, you can create objects on the stack, and without `new`.

Then it looks as if your compiler did not see that `logger` has the constructor taking a stream pointer and a string. From the call you do it assumes the signature has to be *something like* `std::ofstream*&, std::string`, but the constructor you provided perfectly matches that assumption (see Sebastian Redl's answer for details).

So, what could be wrong here?

1. The compiler does not see the header at all. That would be because you did not include it. I don't think this is likely, because the error message should be different then (saying something about the class `logger` has not been defined)
2. The compiler sees another version of the header that does not contain the constructor you mean to call here. That could be because you did not save the header after editing in the constructor, or maybe you copied it into another location and the `#include` directive finds an older version and not the one you put the constructor in. Best possibility to find this out is introducing some clear error in the header and compile again. If the compiler does not complain about the error, it does clearly not include the header you are editing.

Comment: I was using a pointer not because I am emulating Java ( I've actually no experience in it at all ), but because I want several logger classes that write to the same file. I wasn't sure on multiple fstreams to a single file, and since my program is single-threaded, I didn't think using a single stream would cause data racing.

Answer (score 1):

GCC has this weird way of reporting the types of the arguments to a function.

When you do this:

```
logger( stream, std::string("blurp") );
```

the compiler sees a call to the logger constructor (`name::space::logger`) with the first argument being an lvalue (in this case a plain variable) of type `std::ostream*`, and the second being an rvalue (a temporary constructed in-place) of type `std::string`. It reports this as the call signature `(name::space::logger)(std::ostream*&, std::string)` - the `&` (lvalue reference) here merely indicates that the argument is an lvalue. This does not affect the ability to match it to the parameter type `std::ostream*`.

Comment: While this is a really nice and accurate explanation for why the compiler looks for and reports about that exact signature, it is not an explanation why it might not find the function.

Comment: True, I only answered the title of the question.